# Bot Framework Emulator: Unknown Host

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I'm developing a simple Dispatch Bot, I only have a basic structure now to chose between QnA or LUIS models but when I test it in the Bot Framework Emulator, the `AdapterWithErrorHandler` catches and error and i get no response from LUIS neither QnA.

[image: Unknown Host error in the logger] everytime i send a message.

I checked the `appsettings.json` and everything seems to be fine. I want to point out when I created the LUIS App a default key was given to me, and later on i linked it with the Cognitive Resource i have in Azure and a second key was given. Which one do I need to use?

[image: LUIS keys]

I got everything hosted in the West Europe server except the QnAMaker resource (which I haven't read anywhere this should cause any problem).

This is the Emulator Log window, as you can see the problem doesn't occur until I send a message. It looks like it connects properly but then can't find the hosts. The message displayed is from the Adapter that catches de exception.
[image: Emulator Log Window]

**Update:** that might be relevant to the problem, whenever I try to open my csproj file to see its contents this message is displayed:

[image: displayed]

`catastrophic error hresult 0x8000ffff (e_unexpected))`

Comment: Is there any sample that you referred to ?

Comment: The code structure is similar to the DispatchBot sample, but the code is not the same. There is almost nothing programmed, just QnA and LUIS calls to be able to analyze responses in the emulator.

Comment: @FerranCapalleraGuirado I could think of 2 things that might've caused that error. Your host name you used is incorrect--perhaps try "westeurope" if you haven't. See [Europe publishing regions doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions#europe-publishing-regions)

Comment: or, perhaps (and I've done this myself), you haven't published you LUIS model/QnA Knowledge Base

Comment: @Zeryth thank you for your comment, this was indeed the mistake. Stanley below posted an example of his `appsettings.json` file and I saw it immediately but thank you for the answer anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the error you encountered and I have not met this error on my side.

But I run [NLP DispatchBot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) on my side successfully , with the steps below , maybe will helpful for you :

1. I created a LUIS app and a QnA maker for demo, if I query "help" to my LUIS , it will reply "Help" intent, it is deployed on westus:
   [image]

and this is the party content of my QnA maker : 
[image]

2. Mapping appsettings.json file in project : 
   [image]
   `LuisAPIHostName` in your case should be `westeurope`

   3. In my case , if I type help, LUIS will reply "Help" intent so that direct to QnA service, so I modify the matching value in `DispatchBot.cs` file under `DispatchToTopIntentAsync` to make sure "Help" intent can be matched to lead me to QnA service :
      [image]
   4. Test on local: 
      [image]

If you have anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was I had "westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com" in the HostName field instead of only "westeurope". I thought the dispatch bot had a way to distinguish if the message came from LUIS or QnA without having to ask LUIS first and then redirect to the QnA service. Having to type some keyword before every question feels a little artifical. Is there a score in the QnA answers like there is in the LUIS?

Comment: Yes , this doc explained Confidence score of QnA answers  well :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score

Comment: Hi, pls mark my answer  if it solved your issue : )

Comment: Yeah I've read the doc but it didn't explain how to obtain the value. If this is useful for anyone, this link shows it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.queryresult?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable