# How to execute a function(may contain SQL query or programming logic) on certain message received from user

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I want to make my chatbot **dynamic**. I have static knowledge base for my bot but my bot should process some dynamic functions.
Like,

> on message of "today" Bot responds : 9th September 2019 , Saturday
>   10:47 UTC
>
> On message of "my IP" Bot should respond : Your ip is 192.168.xxx.xx 
>                        (which is users local ip)
>
> On message of  "is my network printer working" bot should ping , check
>   and respond with a status :
>                      : Your printer is down right now and maintenance is going on.

I have tried searching some blogs about functions in bot and i got one :
[Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/04/22/azure-bot-function/)
but it "open bot in azure function " is not there that is showed in blog
[image of "open bot in azure function option"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t98D.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to your bot service could understand your input intention and then call the corresponding method to handle users' requests , using [Azure LUIS service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis) will be the proper way to implement to do it .

To be brief, LUIS service is used for getting natural language/text from user and reply them as an intent so that you can handle users' intents by different methods in your code.

The blog you provided just indicated a simple way to demo how to use LUIS with azure bot . Azure function is not a necessary service here.What's more, seems this way is not available anymore.

[This demo which integrated with LUIS and QnA maker](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) will be helpful for you to meet your requirement . You can refer to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669354/bot-framework-emulator-unknown-host/57685342#57685342) about how to run this demo .

If you have anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know : )

Comment: i have done most of Bot work online .Like knowledge base , creating bot app ,services.So for this LUIS integration i have to download the code and work on it right? or another way available?

Comment: Of course you can integrate LUIS service into your code online , the code I provided just demo you how to integrate it .Anyway, it will be easy to do test or debug work on local I think : )